# Create a new file in Lua/LuaFileSystem

Tags: lua

I've looked over the Lua & LuaFileSystem Docs and have yet to find a way to create a new file, I also scouted around on here but to the same end.

As a note, the solution I'm looking for has to be OS neutral to ensure portability, but I'm happy to get different answers for different systems.

Comment: I did find: os.execute("echo   some text > someFileName.txt"); but as I'm letting users have their own filenames I feel that this is probably a bit insecure...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Example (writing "Hello World" into test.txt):

```
$ lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> file = io.open("test.txt", "w")
> file:write("Hello World")
> file:close()
> ^D
$ cat test.txt 
Hello World
```

See also: [Lua IO tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/IoLibraryTutorial)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it was so easy!

Comment: Note that `io.output` followed by `io.write` is unnecessary (like when you have to write to several files at once), you can use `file:write(...)` to write to the file directly.

Comment: It is a good idea to always check results of `io.open()` for errors. Wrap it in `assert()`, for example.